# Adding missing rows to time series data in r

Tags: r

I have a data set of GPS coordinates, however some of the times are missing. I want to add the missing rows in with the appropriate timestamp and NA's for the lat and lon columns

This is how the data is currently formatted:

```
             timestamp      lon       lat    id       date     time
                <time>    <dbl>     <dbl> <int>     <date>    <chr>
1  2012-08-01 03:59:00 36.92288 0.3508941     1 2012-08-01 03:59:00
2  2012-08-01 03:59:01 36.92288 0.3508901     1 2012-08-01 03:59:01
3  2012-08-01 03:59:02 36.92288 0.3508868     1 2012-08-01 03:59:02
4  2012-08-01 03:59:03 36.92288 0.3508828     1 2012-08-01 03:59:03
5  2012-08-01 03:59:05 36.92288 0.3508845     1 2012-08-01 03:59:05
6  2012-08-01 03:59:06 36.92288 0.3508866     1 2012-08-01 03:59:06
7  2012-08-01 03:59:07 36.92288 0.3508885     1 2012-08-01 03:59:07
8  2012-08-01 03:59:08 36.92288 0.3508903     1 2012-08-01 03:59:08
9  2012-08-01 03:59:09 36.92288 0.3508915     1 2012-08-01 03:59:09
```

as you can see timestamp 2012-08-01 03:59:04 is missing I would like to have something like this at the end

```
             timestamp      lon       lat    id       date     time
                <time>    <dbl>     <dbl> <int>     <date>    <chr>
1  2012-08-01 03:59:00 36.92288 0.3508941     1 2012-08-01 03:59:00
2  2012-08-01 03:59:01 36.92288 0.3508901     1 2012-08-01 03:59:01
3  2012-08-01 03:59:02 36.92288 0.3508868     1 2012-08-01 03:59:02
4  2012-08-01 03:59:03 36.92288 0.3508828     1 2012-08-01 03:59:03
5  2012-08-01 03:59:04     NA      NA         1 2012-08-01 03:59:04
6  2012-08-01 03:59:05 36.92288 0.3508845     1 2012-08-01 03:59:05
7  2012-08-01 03:59:06 36.92288 0.3508866     1 2012-08-01 03:59:06
8  2012-08-01 03:59:07 36.92288 0.3508885     1 2012-08-01 03:59:07
9  2012-08-01 03:59:08 36.92288 0.3508903     1 2012-08-01 03:59:08
10 2012-08-01 03:59:09 36.92288 0.3508915     1 2012-08-01 03:59:09
```

Any help with this would be much appreciate!

Comment: Could you share the data with `dput`?

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why, exactly, do you need to simulate data that wasn't recorded?

Comment: @Hack-R the data is available [Here](https://www.datarepository.movebank.org/handle/10255/move.406)

Comment: @brichins I figure the data has been collected at a high enough frequency to make the imputation reasonable. I'm also going to be getting the speed of each individual and want a way to fix any baboons I find going 40mph for a second then going back to a more reasonable speed the next second.

Comment: Ok, so you're looping with a constant increment instead of computing the elapsed time for each step. Makes sense, although with enough missing data points (which I would expect from most GPS logs) you may get better performance by comparing times. Would depend a lot on your data feed and how you're using it though; with a fairly straight 1 point per second imputing makes plenty of sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rbind.fill` from the `plyr` package:

```
ts_data <- read.table(text="timestamp,lon,lat,id,date,time
2012-08-01 03:59:00,36.92288,0.3508941,1,2012-08-01,03:59:00
2012-08-01 03:59:01,36.92288,0.3508901,1,2012-08-01,03:59:01
2012-08-01 03:59:02,36.92288,0.3508868,1,2012-08-01,03:59:02
2012-08-01 03:59:03,36.92288,0.3508828,1,2012-08-01,03:59:03
2012-08-01 03:59:05,36.92288,0.3508845,1,2012-08-01,03:59:05
2012-08-01 03:59:06,36.92288,0.3508866,1,2012-08-01,03:59:06
2012-08-01 03:59:07,36.92288,0.3508885,1,2012-08-01,03:59:07
2012-08-01 03:59:08,36.92288,0.3508903,1,2012-08-01,03:59:08
2012-08-01 03:59:09,36.92288,0.3508915,1,2012-08-01,03:59:09", 
                      header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, sep=",")

##Convert timestamp to datetime
ts_data$timestamp <- ts_data$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(strftime(ts_data$timestamp))

##Get full sequence
full_sequence <- seq(from=min(ts_data$timestamp), 
                     to=max(ts_data$timestamp), by="s")

##Grab the missing sequence
missing_sequence <- full_sequence[!(full_sequence %in% ts_data$timestamp)]

##Make a data.frame out of the missing sequence
missing_df <- data.frame(timestamp = missing_sequence, 
                         id = rep(1,length(missing_sequence)), 
                         date = strftime(missing_sequence, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                         time=strftime(missing_sequence, format = "%H:%M:%S"))
##Combine the two
new_ts_data <- plyr::rbind.fill(ts_data, missing_df)
##Order by timestamp
new_ts_data <- new_ts_data[order(new_ts_data$timestamp),]
```

Desired output:

```
 timestamp           lon      lat       id date       time    
 2012-08-01 03:59:00 36.92288 0.3508941 1  2012-08-01 03:59:00
 2012-08-01 03:59:01 36.92288 0.3508901 1  2012-08-01 03:59:01
 2012-08-01 03:59:02 36.92288 0.3508868 1  2012-08-01 03:59:02
 2012-08-01 03:59:03 36.92288 0.3508828 1  2012-08-01 03:59:03
 2012-08-01 03:59:04       NA        NA 1  2012-08-01 03:59:04
 2012-08-01 03:59:05 36.92288 0.3508845 1  2012-08-01 03:59:05
 2012-08-01 03:59:06 36.92288 0.3508866 1  2012-08-01 03:59:06
 2012-08-01 03:59:07 36.92288 0.3508885 1  2012-08-01 03:59:07
 2012-08-01 03:59:08 36.92288 0.3508903 1  2012-08-01 03:59:08
 2012-08-01 03:59:09 36.92288 0.3508915 1  2012-08-01 03:59:09
```

#### Edit to work with the appropriate dataset

The filtered dataset is saved [here](http://web.mit.edu/aseck/www/filtered_baboons_data.txt) and a fully working script is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qszffvo4lnv53ya/baboons.R?dl=0).

Comment: I tried to use some of my data (see above for link) to test this code and it didn't quite work. I only used 1 ID and day. Test Data `move_dat %>% mutate(date = as.Date(timestamp), time = substr(.$timestamp,12,19)) %>% dplyr::filter(id == 2 & date == "2012-08-01") -> move_dat_tst` Its length is 42984 and the full_sequence length is 43067, so the length of the missing_sequence should be 83. But when I run the code I get a length of 626 which seems like too much.

Comment: Edit I mean the length is 42441 NOT 626

Comment: @Alex, I just ran it with your filtered data and got `84` for the `missing_sequence` vector (because there are duplicates in the main dataset). Are you sure you've properly renamed the variables to fit your script? [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oqoqr68nkt68d11/filtered_baboons_data.csv?dl=0) is the filtered dataset from your main data.

Comment: I figured out what was going on. I don't think the time variable was coded correctly so I recoded it and everything is working perfectly! Thanks!